# creating multiple nodes on top of each other with tap

Tags: swift, skspritenode

What I'm trying to do is when the user taps the screen I want it to create multiple sprites in the same position with a delay in between and the next node added on top of the previous node.

When the node is created it increases in size then fades out, each node is also a different colour so I should be able to see each node on top of the last.

I've tried multiple different iterations to try to get this to work. below is the latest.

```
func createShape(location: CGPoint){
    var positionz:CGFloat = 1

    for i in 1...6{
    let square = SKSpriteNode(color: randomColor(), size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
    square.position = location
    square.zPosition = positionz
    addChild(square)

  let  shapeIncrease = SKAction.resize(toWidth: square.size.width + 50, height: square.size.height + 50, duration: 0.7)
  let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration:0.5)
    //let remove = SKAction(square.removeFromParent())
    let shapeSequence = SKAction.sequence([shapeIncrease, fadeOut, SKAction.removeFromParent()])
square.run(shapeSequence)
        positionz += 1
        print("\(square.color)")
    }

}
```

The problem I'm having is that I can only see one node. The node counter increases and I've confirmed that each node has a different colour but I cant figure out how to get them to appear correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this one. for anyone who's trying to do something similar I ended up putting the node creation in run blocks as part of touches begin per below.

I'm sure there's a much better and cleaner way of doing this but this is working for me so I'm going to stick with it.

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
          let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.15)
        let s1 = SKAction.run {
            self.createShape(location: location, zposition: 1)
        }
        let s2 = SKAction.run {
            self.createShape(location: location, zposition: 2)
        }
        let s3 = SKAction.run {
            self.createShape(location: location, zposition: 3)
        }
        let s4 = SKAction.run {
            self.createShape(location: location, zposition: 4)
        }
        let s5 = SKAction.run {
            self.createShape(location: location, zposition: 5)
        }
        let s6 = SKAction.run {
            self.createShape(location: location, zposition: 6)
        }

          let sequence1 = SKAction.sequence([s1, wait, s2, wait, s3, wait, s4, wait, s5, wait, s6])
       run(sequence1)
```